# what are windows most popular dlls to use with P/INVOKE

Tags: windows, dll, pinvoke

Recently I discovered C#'s P/Invoke. And I want to know which DLL are commonly used and what they are capable of.

I've found this list http://www.win7dll.info/ but it's too big, and doesn't provide any useful description.

What I'm hoping for - is "you can use libxxx.dll for drawing on desktop, and libyyy.dll will allow you to play sound, libzzz.dll gives access to taskbar's preview window" etc...

Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You're better off asking this question the other way around: find the DLL that lets you solve a particular problem.  But it seems that the front page of the site you linked gives you the information you request in the tables of DLLs.  What more do you want?  You can use shell32.dll for manipulating Windows Shell, imageres.dll for manipulating Windows Image Resources...

Comment: You're aware of the MSDN Library, which is where the Win32 API is documented?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300%28v=vs.85%29

Comment: not really, thank's that's a great resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really going about the problem the wrong way around. You don't P/Invoke entire DLLs, you P/Invoke specific functions that are exported from particular DLLs. And therefore you don't care about *which* DLLs exist and what they do, you only care about specific functions that enable you to do specific things. You need to figure out what you want to accomplish, and then figure out how to do it. Lots of things are already wrapped by the .NET Framework so none of your own P/Invoke code is required. If P/Invoke is required, then you'll write that code *after* you know what you want to do and which function you want to call. The questions you should be asking on Stack Overflow are "how do I do *x*?" We'll tell you which functions you need, and from that you'll know which DLLs you need.

Anyway, it's quite hard to provide any better description than the list does. `user32.dll` literally provides user interface components. This includes a vast array of things, from windows to message boxes to displaying text, to processing window messages, to displaying the desktop, and more.

There is [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files) on the most common Windows DLLs. But the information they give is mostly just for curiosity's sake.

Comment: That's actually the answer to this question. This wikipedia article is what I needed to start new journey, thanks.